# Java: Program that places words into a char array not working

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

It's supposed to populate the 2D array with random chars and then inserts the words that were input by the user into the 2D array in places where it wont go out of bounds. It's supposed to add them horizontally, vertically and diagonally, the method I have right now only adds words vertically until I can get it to work correctly.

Or at least, it's intended to since the few times I get the words to output correctly they end up diagonally, I don't understand why. I guess I can just re-label this as the diagonal variation instead of the vertical one, but I'd still like to understand why this is happening.

Also, the way I have it right now makes it so that when an index is found out of bounds while adding a word, it looks for another position to add the word, but it leaves the half-placed word there. I'd want it to only output the word if it completely fits. Sometimes it never finds a good spot and I end up with a StackOverflowError.

Here is some sample input/output:

```
Input:
How many rows would you like? >
5
How many columns would you like? >
5
Add a word to your search(Type end to stop) >
WORD
Add a word to your search(Type end to stop) >
end
```

-

```
Output: 
Before adding:
g m g m c
a t j z l
m z t d u
q o f e q
c p g s g

After adding:
g m g m c
a W j z l
m z O d u
q o f R q
c p g s D
```

Or in some cases with the same output:

```
Before adding:
w a y c c
z l l z u
l c c a v
d h l z d
u d n c h

After adding:
w W y c c
z W O z u
l c O R v
d h l R D
u d n c D
```

Or even:

```
Before adding:
h d o x r
c r t p b
n e r p a
a q m s q
s r d l h

After adding:
W d o x r
c O W p b
n e R O a  //Here there wasn't enough space for WORD
a q m D R  //So it got to WOR and then looked for a new start point
s r d l h
```

And heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BuildWS
{
    private char [][]board;
    private int ROW, COL;
    private String inWord;
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void build()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //takes in user input

        System.out.println("How many rows would you like? >");
        ROW = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many columns would you like? >");
        COL = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        do{
            System.out.println("Add a word to your search (end to stop) >");
            inWord = input.nextLine();

            if(!inWord.equals("end"))
            {
                words.add(inWord);
            }

        }while(!inWord.equals("end"));

        fillBoard(); 

        System.out.println("Before adding:");
        printBoard();

        addWords();

        System.out.println("After adding:");
        printBoard()      

    }

    public void fillBoard()
    {
        board = new char[ROW][COL];

        for(int rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++)
        {
            for(int cols = 0; cols < board[rows].length; cols++)
            {
                board[rows][cols] = randomChar();
            }
        }

    }

    public void addWords()
    {

        int rowPos, colPos, orientation;

        for(String s: words)
        {
            rowPos = (int)(Math.random() * ROW);
            colPos = (int)(Math.random() * COL);

            orientation = 1; //(int)(Math.random() * 2); // 0 = horizontal, 1 = vertical

            if(inBounds(rowPos, colPos))
            {
                if(orientation == 1) //set to 1 for easy testing
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) //go into row once
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; (j < s.length()); j++) //go through columns to the right
                        {
                            if(inBounds(rowPos, colPos)) //if index is in bounds
                            {
                                board[rowPos][colPos] = s.charAt(index); //change element in board to current char of current word

                                rowPos++;
                                colPos++

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                addWords();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                addWords();
            }
        }
    }

    public void printBoard()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public boolean inBounds(int inRow, int inCol)
    {
        return ((inRow >= 0) && (inRow < ROW) && (inCol >= 0) && (inCol < COL));
    }

    public char randomChar()
    {
        char alphabet[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
            'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
            'y', 'z'};

        return alphabet[(char)(alphabet.length * Math.random())];
    }

}
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code to examine what it is doing.

Comment: Suppose you have some chars from first in your vertical column, upon putting the new chars the olf chars could be replaced???

Answer (score 0):

```
rowPos++;
colPos++
```

You are incrementing both the row and column counters here. If you want to add the word vertically, you should only increment the row counter since the column counter should remain constant. (That's what "vertical" means, right?)

p.s. You should probably not call `addWords()` inside itself. This is what we refer to as "recursion" which is a very powerful tool when used correctly. The problem here is that you have no way of stopping the recursion when it occurs and will quickly run out of memory. I am just mentioning it here to give you the correct terminology when you are ready to learn more about this topic.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I missed that. And I changed the else statement according to your advice. Now if it gets into the else it will generate a new random row/column position and set the j counter to -1 so that the for-loop starts from 0 again. There must be better ways of doing this, but at least it gets the job done. Thank you!

Comment: @Bluasul I suggest that you learn some debugging skills which will help you find problems like this. All IDEs come with a source-level debugger which allows you to visually step through your code and examine values of variables. You can also add `System.out.println()` calls to your code for quick and dirty debugging.

Comment: @Bluasul I suspect that your solution for the else statements is not the best. You probably need a loop instead of a simple if statement since you want to keep picking random numbers until one works.